# How to use babel-plugin to specific file via .babelrc?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have lot of `.js` code in my project, but I want to use `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` to `main.js` file without affect to all `.js` files I have.
How can i do that?